# Is JS autocomplete diff from other functions?

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]
});
```

and it works.  If I try to put anything else in there like:

```
$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
alert ("test");
    source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"]
});
```

then it doesn't work and gives this error: syntax error: unexpected string.

I was hoping to make an AJAX call before the source: call so that I can get the data to display to the user. Am I misunderstanding something in how this is supposed to work?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the autocomplete events, i think the "search" event is the one you need, here is a link http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete#event-search

here is an ajax example

```
$( "#user_name" ).autocomplete({
            source: "index.php?option=abc",
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 0,
            autoFocus: true,
            select: function (event, ui) {

                    $("#user_id").val(ui.item.id);
                    $(this).data("user_id",ui.item.id);//Store arbitrary data associated with the specified element
                    $(this).data("username",ui.item.value);//Store arbitrary data associated with the specified element

                },
                selectFirst: true,
                autoFill: true,
                mustMatch: true
            })
            .bind("blur",function() {
                var user_id = $(this).data("user_id");
                var username = $(this).data("username");
                if(typeof username === \'undefined\')
                {
                    username = \'\';
                    user_id = null;
                }
                $(this).val(username);
                $("#user_id").val(user_id);
            })


;
    });//fine autocomplete
```

Comment: yeah that is what I am using, but not sure how to move further than the example.

Comment: oh then what you need is this http://jqueryui.it/demos/autocomplete#remote, plus a script that outputs the data in json format

Comment: but the example there is the same as in the original link. I am just not clear how/where to make the ajax call.

Comment: it's not the same, click "view source", it gives you 
  $( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
   source: "search.php",
   minLength: 2,
   select: function( event, ui ) {
    log( ui.item ?
     "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
     "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
   }
  });

Comment: and this code you showed goes right inside the block of the autocomplete?

Comment: sorry, wrong example, fixed now, anyways a little study of jQuery please, stop guessing

Answer (score 3):

`autocomplete` is taking an object literal as an argument, which is a series of key:value pairs.  `alert("test")` is arbitrary code being put in the middle of it.

```
var obj = {
    key1: "value",   //Okay
    key2: false,     //Still okay
    console.log("Hello, World!")  //Bad
};
```

Comment: so where/how would I make the ajax call to populate the source: ?

Comment: the autocomplete plugin will make the ajax call for you, if `source` is a string instead of an array.  See the [Remote Datasource](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote) example.

Answer (score 1):

.autocomplete() is a jquery plugin or a jquery ui add-on and both have their own method options and syntaxes. If you do anything other than what's been allowed by the authors of the plugins it will not work.

It looks like you want to run some JS before or after the autocomplete. The standalone jquery autocomplete by bassistance.de and the jquery ui version, both have some callback functionality to allow you to this. Google for their documebaantation once you find out which one you are using from your source code.

Comment: I am a bit new to jQuery - what is callback? Is it a different approach than making an AJAX call and getting a string value back?